# Restore not restoring data all the time

Tags: cassandra, restore

I have cassandra 3.7 installed in container and managed by kubernetes
I created a keyspace cathy1 with replication factor 3

Inside the cassandra container on node1, I have created a keyspace *cathy1* as following:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cathy1  WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};

CREATE TABLE cathy1.employees(emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,emp_name text);
INSERT INTO cathy1.employees(emp_id,emp_name) VALUES (1,'cathy');
INSERT INTO cathy1.employees(emp_id,emp_name) VALUES (2,'jon');
```

so each node owns 100% of the data

I run a `cqlsh -f list_tables` on each node:

```
 emp_id | emp_name
--------+----------
      1 |    cathy 
      2 |      jon 
(2 rows)
```

I run on node 2 :

```
nodetool snapshot -t mycathy1-node2 cathy1
```

I see a directory `mycathy1-node2` under `cassandra/data/cathy1/employees* /snapshots` containing this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Oct 18 20:27 manifest.json
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   43 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-CompressionInfo.db 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   96 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--  2 root root    9 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-Digest.crc32 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   16 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-Filter.db 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   32 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-Index.db 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root 4610 Oct 18 20:23 mb-12-big-Statistics.db 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   56 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-Summary.db 
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   92 Oct 18 20:22 mb-12-big-TOC.txt
```

Then I truncate the table

```
cqlsh -e "truncate cathy1.employees"
```

At that moment there are no files under `cassandra/data/cathy1/employees*` on any nodes  
Only the snapshots directory remains

I run a `cqlsh -f list_tables` on each node:

```
 emp_id | emp_name 
--------+---------- 
(0 rows)
```

I run a repair on node 2:

```
nodetool repair cathy1
```

it finishes successfully 
then still on node 2

```
cd cassandra/data/employees* 
cp ./snapshots/mycathy1-node2/* . 

-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Oct 18 20:34 manifest.json 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   43 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-CompressionInfo.db  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   96 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Data.db 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Digest.crc32 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Filter.db 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Index.db 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4610 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Statistics.db 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   56 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-Summary.db 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   92 Oct 18 20:34 mb-12-big-TOC.txt 
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:29 snapshots
```

Then I run `nodetool refresh employees` 
I run a `cqlsh -f list_tables` on each node:

```
 emp_id | emp_name
--------+----------
(0 rows)
```

I run `nodetool repair cathy1` 
 
and there is still no data visible !!!!!

```
    Pending Flushes: 0 <br>
            Table: employees <br>
            Space used (live): 4954 <br>
            Space used (total): 4954 <br>
            Space used by snapshots (total): 59873 <br>
            Off heap memory used (total): 32 <br>
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.75 <br>
            **Number of keys (estimate): 4** <br>
```

Even if statistics says there are 4 keys in table `cathy1.employees`

```
nodetool flush cathy1
```

still no data visible with cqlsh

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **sstableloader** at the directory where you've copied your snapshot files.

```
sstableloader -d <node_ip> -u cassandra -pw cassandra <directory_location>
```

Note: If your current directory is the directory you have copied your snapshot file, then you don't need to put anything at the field *directory_location*.

For more details about sstableloader: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html

Comment: why do I need to run sstableloader? documentation says nodetool refresh does the same.

Comment: Why do I see keys in cfstats for table employees but select * shows no data ?

Comment: To backing up data and restoring you can use many ways. You can backup and restore your data without taking any snapshots too (COPY TO CSV and COPY FROM CSV). For me, I successfully backup and restored my data using snapshot with the help of sstableloader. It works fine.